# Get file content with Google Apps Script Advanced Drive API - Drive.Files.get - or export

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to get the file content of a text file using the Google Apps Script **Advanced Drive Service**.  This question is specific to Google Apps Script.

It is possible to get file content by making an HTTPS Request using the Drive API, but I don't want to make an HTTPS Request.  So, I'm **not asking for a "work around" or a way that does not use the Advanced Drive Service**.

It *is* possible to get file content using an HTTPS Request to the Drive REST API using the file's self link and the "alt=media" option.  But I don't want to do it that way, because I want to avoid the need for the user to authorize an external request.

Here is the way that I am doing it now with the Drive REST API.

```
function getContentsOfTxtFile_(po) {
try{
  var i,options,rtrnObj,selfLink,tkn,url;
  /*
    PASSED IN PARAMETERS
    po.id - the file id of the text file to get
  */
  
  selfLink = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + po.id;
  url = selfLink + '?alt=media';//using alt=media returns the file content instead of the metadata resource

  tkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();//Get the OAuth token

  options = {};
  options.headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tkn}
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;

  for (i=1;i<3;i++) {//Only loop twice because sometimes there will legitimately not be a file
  try{
    rtrnObj = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);//Make an external request to get the file content
    break;//If successful break out of the loop
  } catch(e) {
    if (i!==2) {Utilities.sleep(i*1500);}
    if (i>=2) {
      console.log('ERROR getting file content: ' + e + "Stack: " + e.stack)
    }
  };
  }
  
  if (!rtrnObj) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (rtrnObj.getResponseCode() !== 200) { 
    return false;
  }
  return rtrnObj.getContentText();
}catch(e){
  console.error('Error ' + e)
}
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
function getFileContent() {
  try{
    var content = Drive.Files.get('File ID Here',{alt:'media'});
  }catch(e) {
    Logger.log('message: ' + e.message)
  } 
  
}
```

The above code generates the error:

> message: Response Code: 200. Message: File content is here

It is also possible to get a "Web Content Link" from the files metadata, and to then use the webContentLink to:

Quote:

> A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is
> only available for files with binary content in Google Drive

Documentation at: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

I have tried:

```
function getFileContentW_Export() {
  try{
    var content = Drive.Files.export('FileID?alt=media','text/plain');
  }catch(e) {
    Logger.log('message: ' + e.message)
  } 
  
  Logger.log('content: ' + content)
}
```

OR:

```
var content = Drive.Files.export('FileID','text/plain');
```

It seems that the Advanced Drive API is not able to get file content.  It seems like this capability was intentionally omitted from the Advanced Drive API, even though the REST API is capable of getting file content.

I issued a bug report in the issue tracker, but the lack of this capability is not considered to be a bug.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149104685

I'd gladly use `DriveApp` if I could use it with the scope `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"` but [`DriveApp.getFileById('ID')` won't work with that scope](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112272756).  The following code:

```
var content = DriveApp.getFileById('ID').getAs(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT).getDataAsString();
```

Returns an error of:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById.
> Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
> || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

Even the "readonly" scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is restricted.  See: "Gmail and Drive APIs" in section at link: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=en#getFileById(String)

Comment: *results in an error.* What's the error?

Comment: See update. `message: Response Code: 200. Message: File content is here`

Comment: Why don't use [DriveApp.getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app.html#getFileById(String))

Comment: I'm trying to exclusively use the Advanced Drive Service with the scope `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"` in order to restrict the permissions that I need to ask users for.  The code is in an add-on, and I don't want to ask for full access to the users Drive.  That would result in needing to go through a special security assessment which costs $15,000 dollars to get the add-on approved by Google.

Comment: Doesn't ``DriveApp`` work with `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"`? The only condition I know (to use `drive.file`) is  that the script should've created/opened the file  you're requesting. Is the file created by your script?

Comment: Testing, I was able to get text content using `getFileContent` for a `.txt` file

Comment: What is the full line of code?  Is this with DriveApp?

Comment: Code is exactly as given in your question. Logger.log(e.message) gives the content. Even works with  image files->I get garbled binary data. I'm assuming "File content is here" is the actual content of the file you're trying to get to.

Comment: The logged error message truncates the file content.  I tried with a text file of length of 2210 and it returned 1030 characters.  Also, using `DriveApp.getFileById(id)` can NOT be used with scope `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"`  Even the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is restricted.  See: [https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes)  So, I'm back to using a GET request to get the file content which means using the external request permission.

Comment: In the case of `Drive.Files.export`, although this cannot be seen at the code completion of the script editor, when `{alt: "media"}` is added like `Drive.Files.export('FileID','text/plain',{alt: "media"})`, the content can be confirmed at `e.message`. But in this case, all content cannot be retrieved because of the error log. So I also think that it's a bug of Advanced Google services. But if I found the method for downloading the content using Advanced Google services, I would like to tell it.

Comment: did you try to remove ?alt=media from your FileID in export? You can do test in [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), in **fileId** put an ID and in **mimeType** text/plain. I tested and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `var content = Drive.Files.export('fileID','text/plain');` and got error: "API call to drive.files.export failed with error: Export requires alt=media to download the exported content"  The "Try this API" probably doesn't use the Advanced Drive Service which is a little different than the Drive REST API.

Comment: @AlanWells I tried with different **mimeTypes**, the one which gives me even more data is `text/html`. If it's possible, can you share a sample document which you are trying to work with? I will do tests and will let you know.

Comment: The context information in the code editor for `Drive.Files.export()` is wrong.  It doesn't show a third parameter, which it seems it will take.  For example:`var content = Drive.Files.export('file ID','text/plain',{alt:'media'})`  But when I do that, I get the error: `API call to drive.files.export failed with error: Export only supports Google Docs`  So, the advanced Drive Service for export seems to have some issues.  Are you using the Advanced Drive Service in your tests?  As opposed to the "Try this API"

Comment: @AlanWells Ran into this problem today and appreciated your question here and the issue you submitted. I just added a comment to the latter which reiterated the points you made and added my discovery that if the content of the file in question is valid json, then the get() succeeds(!) and returns the content as the equivalent Javascript object!!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot totally solve you problem, but hope it could provide some help.

`Files.export()` should be as the following format:

```js
const content = Drive.Files.export(id, 'text/plain', {alt:'media'});
```

If you try to open a .txt file:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.export failed
> with error: Export only supports Docs Editors files.

If it is converted into a document file:

> HttpResponseException: Response Code: 200. Message: File content is here.

Which is the same as `Files.get()` with `{alt:'media'}`

Comment: Thanks. Turns out converting to doc files is not an acceptable workaround for various reasons, though.

Answer (score -2):

I tested different scopes : **drive** and **drive.file** for `Files.export()` and `Files.get()`

Only **drive.file** scope gave me 404

Why?

Because **drive.file** is used for *files created or opened by the app*

Check it here : [Authenticate your users](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing)

```
function fileExport(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
  drive.files.export({
      fileId: fileId,
      mimeType: "text/plain"
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

for files created in drive, use:

```
function fileGet(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
  drive.files.get({
      fileId: fileId
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: There is no class `google` in AppScript.  I'm using the Advanced Drive Service, which when enabled, shows the `Drive` class in the code editor.  How will `google.drive()` work in a "gs" file in Apps Script?

Comment: @Alan Just curious: How is this condition *Because drive.file is used for files created or opened by the app* satisfied by your script?

Comment: @AlanWells I used node.js for test purposes. So you can understand how it works.

Comment: @TheMaster Check it here : [Authenticate your users](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing) https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file : Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.

Comment: My Apps Script project uses the Google File picker, which the user uses in order to designate what files the Apps Script project has access to.  As soon as the user selects a file with the Google File picker, then somehow Google "knows" internally that the scope can access that file.  If the Apps Script project creates a PDF file, then it can access that file because the Apps Script project created the file.

Comment: My question is specific to the Advanced Drive Service used inside of the Apps Script code editor.  The Google Drive API does have SDK's for different languages, but each SDK would have it's own unique differences that don't translate directly to the Advanced Drive Service.

Comment: @AlanWells i have the same issue and also when i use drive and open the picker i get a sign in button which doesn't work (no auth showing to validate scopes) but when i use /drive it works without sign in. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: My issue is not with the Google File Picker.  My Apps Script project can access files that were chosen by the user with the Google File Picker.   I have access to the file that I want to get the file content from, and I'm able to get the file content with the Drive REST API.  But I don't want to use the Drive REST API, I want to use the Advanced Drive Service.  If you have a question about the Google File Picker, you can either ask a new question, or maybe join the [Apps Script Community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community)