# Can anything done with google apps scripts be done with the google API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-docs-api

I noticed that the Google Apps Script editor uses a Bearer token to make requests for a lot of things, that got me thinking: Is it possible to do all functions that are done with the google apps script with the google API on your own server? What is the essential difference? Just the fact that google apps script runs on google servers, while with the google API you would need to create your own servers?

For example many of the document functions, which I thought could only be done with the API, turns out can be found here https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#InsertInlineImageRequest

so whats the essential difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just the fact that google apps script runs on google servers, while with the google API you would need to create your own servers?

Yes. There are advantages to both methods:

#### API:

- It's a rest API. You can use your own language(eg: Python) in your servers.
- The api is more inclusive. There are  stuff which can be done with the api, which cannot be accomplished  with apps script.
- User can set limited scopes for using API.

  - For example, at Drive API, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` can be used for Drive API. The same cannot be done with `DriveApp` of apps script.
- Process cost of API is lower than that of the built-in methods for Google Apps Script[<sup>1</sup>](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) [<sup>2</sup>](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7)

#### Apps script:

- No server on your side
- Triggers. You can set up functions to run onEdit,onOpen or at a specific time.
- Deep integration with Google apps: Sidebars/modal dialogs can only be done with apps script.
- All methods of the api can be accessed indirectly through the bearer token.
- Authorization/authentication is taken care of by apps script. You don't need to set up oauth.

Comment: Interesting, I  have a question on "All methods of the api can be accessed indirectly through the bearer token.", is that the same essentailly as the last point? Also I haven't tested it but is it possible to use the bearer token from google apps script on any server using the google API or is it linked to the script.google.com domain?

Comment: @blue 1.To set up oauth with your server, you need to register  with Google, get client id, secret and then provide a button/ any other method to make the user(or yourself) provide access to your Google account and resources. Read about 2-legged/3-legged oauth flow. All this is automatically done by apps script. 2. The bearer token is essentially a 1 hour password and can be used in any server, but getting the token is a different matter entirely(it's easy with apps script, whereas you need a full oauth flow with your server).

Comment: Oh right I forgot about the bearer token expiring... another question though, is an app made with google apps script limited to any specific quotas that an app made with the google api is not, or visa versa?

Comment: @blue Both have quotas and limitations. You can read about it in their respective  docs. For eg, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas and https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits

Comment: As two more advantages for using API, I think that the user can set the scopes for using API. For example, at Drive API, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` can be used for Drive API. In this case, Drive service cannot be set. Another is that the process cost of API is lower than the built-in methods for Google Apps Script. For example, at Sheets API, there are these benchmarks. [Ref1](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) and [Ref2](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7)

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. Feel free to directly add the points to the answer by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I added them. Could you please confirm it? If you are required to modify, please modify it.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I edited it a bit. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for editing it. I could study from it. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike you could also change the scopes in the google apps script by going to preferences and modifying the manifest file to access specific scopes

Comment: Also is there anything stopping someone, or is there any reason not to, simply send the oauth token from the apps script to a server via urlfetchapp.fetch, and have that function run on a trigger every hour or 45 minutes or so?

Comment: @blue 1. Nothing would stop that (other than quotas). However,That would be a bad idea from a security perspective. 2.Also, Tanaike is aware of that. But, As written in the answer, You can't use much more limited scope- specifically, you can't use the `drive.file` scope with `DriveApp`. You can change the manifest, but it still isn't enough for DriveApp to function. [That difference should cost $15k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153938/get-file-content-with-google-apps-script-advanced-drive-api-drive-files-get#comment106402198_60153938)