# autoResizeColumns Takes Too Long to Process

Tags: google-apps-script

I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why my script takes so long to process. I ended up realizing the culprit was `autoResizeColumns()`. The more rows on a sheet the longer it takes. It takes about a minute for about 6K rows. In my case I had to call it twice on two different sheets, both about 6K rows.

Is there really no other option? Doing this action manually on a sheet using the mouse takes significantly less time. So my question to you is what methods are you using to resize columns automatically?

Comment: Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample script for replicating your situation? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I'm not really asking for any code specifically. If you think you can code something faster than autoResizeColumns then any data set with 6K rows or more would work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about `I'm not really asking for any code specifically.`. In that case, how about trying to use Sheets API?

Comment: @Cooper I don't see anything wrong with my question as presented. Did you read it? Also, I do not have the ability to share outside of my company's network.

Comment: @Tanaike, does Sheets API offer a solution? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Comment: Thank you for replying. Using Sheets API have the advantage of the reduction of process cost. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246768/7108653) But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, because I'm not sure about your actual situation. So I just proposed to try to use Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service of SpreadsheetApp. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll take a look at this and see what I can do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Using the Advanced Sheets Service<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)</sup> you can build a batch request<sup>[[2]](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)</sup> in Google Apps Script for your Sheet which auto resizes the columns for you.*

#### Building the Batch Request:

After enabling the Advanced Sheets Service from the `Resources > Advanced Google services...` menu option and clicking the `On` switch, you can build a batch request as a JSON object.

The structure of your batch request will have to look something like this:

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "autoResizeDimensions": {
        "dimensions": {
          "sheetId": "your-sheet-id",
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": X,
          "endIndex": Y
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `X` and `Y` are integers representing the first and last columns you wish to have auto-resized. You can find more information about it in the 'Automatically resize a column' section<sup>[[3]](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#automatically_resize_a_column)</sup> of the 'Row and Column Operations' documentation<sup>[[4]](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn)</sup>.

**NB: The `startIndex` and `endIndex` values are array-like and so start at 0. If you wish to update the first 1000 columns you must use a `startIndex` of 0 and and `endIndex` of 999.**

#### Example Code:

```js
function resizeColumns() {
  // You can still use the SpreadsheetApp methods to get the Spreadsheet
  // and Sheet IDs which you need for the batch request
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("Name-of-Sheet-to-resize").getSheetId();

  // Define the range of columns
  var X = 0;
  var Y = 999;
  
  // Build the batch resource
  var resource = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "autoResizeDimensions": {
        "dimensions": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": X,
          "endIndex": Y
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
  // Make the batch request
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
  
}
```

#### References:

1. [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)
2. [Method: `spreadsheets.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
3. [Google Sheets > API v4 - Row and Column Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn)
4. [Automatically resize a column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#automatically_resize_a_column)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm getting the following error: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[0].auto_resize_dimensions.dimensions.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "Sheet" (line 151, file "Common Scripts")`

Comment: Line 151 is the line to make the batch request. The very last line of code.

Comment: Is this script bound to your Spreadsheet, or is it standalone? Also: `ss.getId()` should be the file ID of the Spreadsheet file, whereas the variable `sheetId` should be the ID of the individual sheet within the Spreadsheet that you wish to make the request on. These are different, have you modified the provided script at all?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That helped but then I get the following error: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].autoResizeDimensions: No grid with id: 70272574 (line 151, file "Common Scripts")`

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `sheetId` in the request resource? Are you perhaps trying to modify the sheet contained in a different spreadsheet? This error is because the sheet ID you're passing in the request resource is not a member of the Spreadsheet you're making the batch request on.

Comment: I got it figured out. It was a typo on my end. Thanks for the help. I can say that this is much faster than the `autoResizeColumns()` option.

Answer (score 1):

[Sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) is usually faster and can be accessed from apps script through [advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)

Comment: I was looking at that link and I have a ways to go to figure that out. Looks like python is used? I'm debating just leaving it as is and not changing the size of the column.