# Exporting files from Google Drive GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a Google form. I plan to receive PDF documents and Images from users. All answers from the form are saved in the Google sheet.

Next, I need to send this document along with other text fields to my web service.

I found a method to export files from Google Drive by ID - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export

However, due to corporate policy, I don't have enough rights to create OAuth 2.0 accesses - https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/apis/credentials?supportedpurview=project

How else can I export files from Google drive?

```
function Main() {

  let arr = new Array()
  let table = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`Ответы на форму (1)`)
  let count = table.getLastRow()
  let record = table.getRange(count, 2, 1, 16).getValues()

  let email = record[0][0]
  let permission = record [0][1]
  let organization = record[0][2]
  let phone = record[0][3]
  phone = phone.substr(2)
  let target = record[0][6]
  let fullName = record[0][7].trim()
  let gender = record[0][8]
  let inn = record[0][9].toString()
  let snils = record[0][10].toString()
  let passport = record[0][11].toString()
  let issueDate = record[0][12]
  let issueOrganizationId = record[0][13].toString()
  let birthDate = record[0][14].toString()
  let file = record[0][15].replace('https://drive.google.com/open?id=', '').replace('https://drive.google.com/file/d/','').replace('/view?usp=sharing','').trim()

  arr.push(email, organization, phone, target, fullName, gender, inn, snils, passport, issueDate, issueOrganizationId,birthDate, file)
  Logger.log (arr)

  if (record[0][1] == 'Перевыпуск ЭП' && record[0][2] == 'Нет, не менялись') {
    try {
      //API_Renew(organization, email, phone)
    } catch (err) {
      SendEmail(err, email)
    }
  }
  else {
    try {
      //API_New(organization, email, fullName, phone, passport, inn, snils, target, gender, issueDate, issueOrganizationId, birthDate, file)
    } catch (err) {
      SendEmail(err, email)
    }
  }
}


function API_New (organization, email, fullName, phone, passport, inn, snils, target, gender, issueDate, issueOrganizationId, birthDate, file) {

  fullName = fullName.split(' ')

  let payload = [
    {
      "Organization": organization,
      "LastName": fullName[0],
      "FirstName": fullName[1],
      "MiddleName": fullName[2],
      "Email": email,
      "Phone": phone,
      "Series": passport.substring(0, 4),
      "Number": passport.substring(4),
      "Inn": inn,
      "Snils": snils,
      "Target": target, 
      "Gender": gender,
      "IssueDate": issueDate,
      "IssueOrganizationId": issueOrganizationId,
      "BirthDate": birthDate,
      "File": file
    }
  ]

  let options =                                                                                                         //Параметры отправки запроса (POST + ключ разработчика)
  {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }

  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options)
}
```

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand the specification of the API you want to use, only the direct link of the file can be used for the API you want to use. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Do you get any errors when running that script? What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Yes, based on the answers in Google Form, I get a field with a link to a document on Google drive. Example URL - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b8-BOaSOgAuv8AUDhk5DYzOs_phlJy50

Next I need to export this document to my web service. 

No, I don't get any errors when running this script. I need to export the file to my web service along with the rest of the data from my script. 

I can't attach an example reproducing the problem. After all, I'm expecting an example of how to export a PDF document from Google Drive.

Comment: The expected result is that the file is exported from Google Drive to my web service. 
The actual result is that I do not know how to export a file from Google Drive because I have restrictions for OAuth 2.0 authorization and I cannot use this method - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70122294/17926478) answer your question? You only need to enable the advanced Drive service in your Apps Script project. Since this is through Apps Script, you don't need to create credentials in the Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments!

I found 2 ways to export files from Google Drive.

Without connecting additional services:

```
function exportPDF_url (url) {
    let request = 
    {
        method: "GET", 
        headers: { "Authorization":"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
    }
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, request).getBlob();
}
```

With the connection of the Drive API service in the Apps Script project:

```
function exportPDF_id (url) {
  let fileID = url.replace('https://drive.google.com/open?id=', '')
  return  DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
}
```