Drive.Files.export not working in Apps Script
We're trying to export a Google doc to word using the Advanced Drive service v3 in Google Apps script.
Looking at the documentation it should be straight forward:

"Drive.Files.export(fileId: string, mimeType: string): void
Exports a Google Workspace document to the requested MIME type and returns exported byte content. Note that the exported content is limited to 10MB. "

So then we try this
let file= DriveApp.getFileById("DriveFileIdHere");
let excelFile = Drive.Files.export(file.getId(), MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);

And get this:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.export failed with error: Export requires alt=media to download the exported content.

So trying to add that to the call (undocumented)
let excelFile = Drive.Files.export(file.getId(), MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD, {alt:'media'});

We get this:

HttpResponseException: Response Code: 200. Message: PK��Ï½X���������������word/header1.xmlíZmsÛ

What are we missing?

I guessed that your question might be related to this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60153938 I guess that it might still be a bug or the current specification on the Google side. If you want to export the file, in the current stage, please directly request the endpoint with UrlFetchApp.

The output that you see is a bytes arrangement
According to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export
The mimeTypes are listed
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22exportFormats%22%7D
{
  "exportFormats": {
    "application/vnd.google-apps.document": [
      "application/rtf",
      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
      "text/html",
      "application/pdf",
      "application/epub+zip",
      "application/zip",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "text/plain"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.vid": [
      "video/mp4"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet": [
      "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
      "text/tab-separated-values",
      "application/pdf",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
      "text/csv",
      "application/zip",
      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.jam": [
      "application/pdf"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.script": [
      "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation": [
      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
      "application/pdf",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
      "text/plain"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.form": [
      "application/zip"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing": [
      "image/svg+xml",
      "image/png",
      "application/pdf",
      "image/jpeg"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.site": [
      "text/plain"
    ],
    "application/vnd.google-apps.mail-layout": [
      "text/plain"
    ]
  }
}

That being said the export will return the bytes converted in one of the mytypes listed
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export#response-body
more details about download files
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads
I hope this helps you
